# efficient update of objective function in pyomo (for re-solving)

Tags: pyomo

I have a model that I need to solve many times, with different objective function coefficients.
Naturally, I want to spend as little time as possible on updating the model.
My current setup is as follows (simplified):

Abstract model:

```py
def obj_rule(m):
    return sum(Dist[m, n] * m.flow[m,n] for (m,n) in m.From * m.To)
m.obj = Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=minimize)
```

After solve, I update the *concrete* model instance `mi` this way, we new values in `Dist`:

```py
mi.obj = sum(Dist[m, n] * mi.flow[m,n] for (m,n) in mi.From * mi.To)
```

However, I see that the update line takes a lot of time - ca. 1/4 of the overall solution time, several seconds for bigger cases.
Is there some faster way of updating the objective function?
(After all, in the usual way of saving an LP model, the objective function coefficients are in a separate vector, so changing them should not affect anything else.)

Comment: You could make a second `dist2[m,n]` model object, and then make 2 objective functions in your model at the start and activate/deactivate them.  That might help.  Also, is your model “fully connected” in the from->to sense?  If not, I would subset that in larger models to only feasible connections and use that set, which might be a huge improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a reason to define an Abstract model before creating your Concrete model? If you define your concrete model with the rule you show above, you should be able to just update your data and re-solve the model without a lot of overhead since you do don't redefine the objective object. Here's a simple example where I change the values of the cost parameter and re-solve.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
a = list(range(2)) # set the variables define over

#%% Begin basic model
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.c = pyo.Param(a,initialize={0:5,1:3},mutable=True)

model.x = pyo.Var(a,domain = pyo.Binary)
model.con = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.x[0] + model.x[1] <= 1)

def obj_rule(model):
    return(sum(model.x[ind] * model.c[ind] for ind in a))

model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule=obj_rule,sense=pyo.maximize)

#%% Solve the first time
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')

res=solver.solve(model)
print('x[0]: {} \nx[1]: {}'.format(pyo.value(model.x[0]),
                                   pyo.value(model.x[1])))
# x[0]: 1
# x[1]: 0
      

#%% Update data and re-solve
model.c.reconstruct({0:0,1:5})

res=solver.solve(model)
print('x[0]: {} \nx[1]: {}'.format(pyo.value(model.x[0]),
                                   pyo.value(model.x[1])))
# x[0]: 0
# x[1]: 1
```

Comment: This does not work for me on python 3.8 + pyomo 5.7.1 - the `reconstruct` call does not change the model, so the solution does not change. (I can see that the model is unchanged by saving it to an .lp file.)

Comment: Hmm, I'm running pyomo 5.6.6 so I guess the bug mentioned [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/252) hasn't effected me. The link talks about a workaround to clear the component's `_data` dictionary before calling `reconstruct`. Can you try that on your model to see if the values change? If so, I'll update the solution.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help - neither in your example nor in my code. The scary thing is that according to you link, this bug has existed since 2015!
I have now given up Pyomo and rewritten the model in Xpress Python libraries, the model construction and update is an order of magnitude faster this way...

Comment: `reconstruct` was taken out of version 6 of PYOMO